# After recreating a project, Interface Builder connections work but can't be modified

Tags: xcode, interface, builder, iboutlet

I had an old project (iOS 3-era) that I was updating to iOS 5. I had some problems migrating the project automatically and ended up creating a new project and copying all the files over. Everything works fine so far, with one bizarre issue. Many of the nib files have a warning exclamation point next to some of their connections in interface builder; when I mouse over them it says "[view controller name] does not have an outlet named [outlet name]". When I run the project these files still work fine, but when I try to create a new connection it doesn't show any outlets related to the File's Owner, and when I type in the Parent Class name to make sure it is correct it doesn't autocomplete to the class name.

I had renamed some of the files when I copied them over, so that could have something to do with it. Searching online I see people solved similar issues by using the file > read class files in IB, but IB is not standalone in new versions of xcode and this option doesn't appear on the xcode file menu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but just in case someone runs into this.  I solved it by going to "Identity Inspector" and changing the "Class" drop down to the correct file.  So after copying or recreating a project don't for get to re-associate the Identity Inspector Class.

Comment: Same thing happened to me.  This fixed it. Thanks!